# net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, single-page-application

I am getting the `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` error in ASP.NET Core when I try to request my Web API from an SPA.

The first solution to fix the issue was to go my ASP.NET Core address from browser `Advanced` - `Proceed to localhost (unsafe)` and after that the requests from my SPA would work. But I would have to repeat the procedure each time I am starting to work on my project.

[image]

Another solution I found was [this](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopingLocallyWithASPNETCoreUnderHTTPSSSLAndSelfSignedCerts.aspx). In a nutshell the solution is to run the command: `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`. I am on Windows, so according to the linked article `On Windows it'll get added to the certificate store`.

But after I run the command I am still getting the `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` issue on requests. What could I do about it?

Comment: After running the command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`, we need to close and reopen the browser.

Comment: @CSS thanks for the tip.  I tried everything below and it didn't work until closed and reopened my browser.  

Comment: I ran edge in Visual Studio, but it would not work until after I closed all instances of Edge on my PC. Then running the app worked.

Comment: I also found I had to close all instances of my browser (In my case Google Chrome) before it started accepting the Certificate. I believe it must load the trusted certificates on start up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your application, add a reference to the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate via NuGet package. Then in the Startup.ConfigureServices method write this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(
        CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddCertificate();

    // All other service configuration
}
```

Also add app.UseAuthentication(); in the Startup.Configure method. Otherwise, the HttpContext.User will not be set to ClaimsPrincipal

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
   app.UseAuthentication();

    // All other app configuration
}
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @MarkEntingh, the answer is correct. You should check the linked source more carefully if you have any doubts.

Comment: It's strange, the app works correctly on two other developer machines. This third one (a fresh install of VS2019) has the problem. When I tried this suggestion on that machine, the result changed from ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID to 403 (Forbidden). Perhaps this authentication module interferes with the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` we were already using?

Comment: I found that by reversing the order of the calls — by calling `AddAuthentication` before `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApiAuthentication` — the error disappears from Chrome, but Firefox shows a new error (`MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT` in Network | Security subtab)

Answer (score 42):

Do this in the order

1. dotnet dev-certs https --clean
2. Remove your keys and pem from `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\https`
3. dotnet dev-certs https --trust
4. Run SPA project with     "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start"

If you run your project(Point 4) before anything else. The authority is not trusted(done by 3) and results in authority invalid errors

Comment: Perfect, that sorted it for me - thanks!

Comment: Steps 1-3 worked for me. I don't know how or where to do #4 so maybe it was already set like that but running it with the play button just worked.

Comment: Somehow I don't have /ASP.NET under /Roaming.

Comment: Important: reopen google chrome if you have another windows

Answer (score 26):

Running the command `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` will create a self-signed certificate in your device. This certificate will be issued to the `localhost` domain. In my case, after running it, the certificate was created but it was not added to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

[image: certmgr.msc]

To add the certificate, you will need to open `certmgr.msc` (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and run `certmgr.msc`), then go to "Personal" certificates and export the `.cer` certificate issued to `localhost` with the correct expiration time.

If you cannot find the certificate there, you can go to the browser and click on the not secure connection icon, then open the invalid certificate and go to the Details tab and click "Copy to File...", which should create also a `.cer` certificate.

[image: browser certificate]

Next, go to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" and import the certificate there. Once that is done, the certificate will be valid in your local machine. You may need to restart the browser and the service.

Comment: for me executing "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" in command line as admin solved the problem

Comment: I had to restart VS as well.

Comment: After trying for hours with "dotnet dev-certs https --clean / --trust / --check" i tried 
this solution (exporting from personal and importing into trusted) and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: you export from personal and import into trusted by just dragging the certificate in the other folder, in the certmgr.msc

Answer (score 22):

In my case this worked:

Clean the old certificate and generate a new trusted one. Run the commands listed below:

1. dotnet dev-certs https --clean
2. dotnet dev-certs https --trust

### **Go to %APPDATA%\Microsoft\UserSecrets and delete all of the directories --> this is very important**

Re-run the application. It should now run with no SSL errors

source: https://joeblogs.technology/2021/11/neterr_cert_date_invalid/

Comment: This did it for me in Asp .Net Core 8. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu, you need some extra steps:

1. Run `sudo apt-get install libnss3-tools`
2. Run `ls $HOME/.pki/nssdb` to check if this directory exists.
3. If not, then run `mkdir $HOME/.pki/nssdb`to create the directory.
4. Export the certificate with `dotnet dev-certs https` then `sudo -E dotnet dev-certs https -ep /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/https.crt --format PEM`
5. Run the commands `sudo certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "P,," -n localhost -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/https.crt` and
   `sudo certutil -d sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb -A -t "C,," -n localhost -i /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/aspnet/https.crt`

Restart the browser.

More details in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Clinux-ubuntu#trust-https-certificate-on-linux-using-edge-or-chrome) (for Ubuntu and other Linux distros too).

Comment: THANK YOU! I really thought I was going to guess my way by deciphering what the Windows people do. (C drive? Not unique root? Really? Still?) I mean: Windows is amazing! I'm just thankful I don't have to use it. (For now.)

Answer (score 1):

While we all wish that "dotnet dev-certs https --trust" did all these chores; the reality is that Microsoft's tools are not that robust. It only wasted 5 hours in my case!

A lot of clues came from various StackOverflow.com answers including that of @trixo on this very thread.

### Stop IIS Express

by right clicking on its tray icon and then click on Exit

### On the command prompt issue the following commands

- dotnet dev-certs https --clean
- dotnet dev-certs https --trust

### Repair IIS Express

Control Panel > Programs and Features > Locate IIS Express > right click and click on "Repair"

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Open C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https

[image]

Step 2: Check if `.pfx` file of the application is available which is generating error `net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID` while running the application and delete it.

Step 3: Rerun the application.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I couldn't solve it with any of the above methods.
The definitive solution was to do the repair via visual studio installer.
Open visualStudio -> Get tools and features -> Other -> Select Repair

Answer (score -1):

I just changed project from *http**s*** to *http* and it worked.

Answer (score -2):

I followed these steps and it didn't stop the "Not secure" message appearing in Chrome. So then I tried commenting the following line //app.UseHttpsRedirection(); in startup.cs in the Configure() method and it fixed the problem.

Comment: If you comment `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` out all that does is bypass the issue. It's just telling the application to not redirect to https. Example if you usually spin up `https://localhost:5001`, commenting this out would spin up `http://localhost:5000` and yes you would not get the error anymore as it's no longer using https. I guess which is fine if you don't require to using https.

Comment: I tired the answer and didn't work, then I tried this as well and it didn't work. I don't understand why they got to protect a simple ASP .NET server and angualr project like it is a terrorist attack via the net.